# Defining a character array in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to define a character array in SAS, I am following [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf). I actually want to have something like

```
ARRAY test {2} "10,5" "9,0"
```

so a character array where the characters are numeric. I have not defined them before and the paper they say:

> Variables that are not previously defined as character variables will
>   default to numeric variables unless they are  defined as character
>   variables within the ARRAY stat ement. To define character variables
>   within the ARRAY  statement, place a dollar sign ($) after the
>   brackets and before any of the variables, as illustrated in this
>   example

so

```
ARRAY test {2}$ $"10,5" $"9,0"
```

but ofcourse this also does not work. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using parenthesis. something like below

```
 data have;
  ARRAY test {2} $ ("10,5", "9,0");
run;
```